# GStreamer 1.2.4 with Blackmagic Intensity Pro: Can't grab video in 1080p50, only 720p50 possible

Tags: video, ubuntu-14.04, gstreamer

I hope some of you can help me out.

My setup / configuration:

- Amazon FireTV, resolution set to 1080p50
- 1x2 HDMI splitter / HDFury3
- Blackmagic Intensity Pro PCI card
- Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, kernel: 4.2.0-35-generic
- Latest Blackmagic drivers for Linux (Desktop Video 10.6.2)
- GStreamer 1.2.4 including all the necessary plug-ins like bad, ugly etc.

I can successfully grab in 720p50 (FiteTV resolution set to 720p50) using the HDMI-via-Splitter or Component-via-HDFury3 connection:

```
gst-launch-1.0 decklinksrc connection=HDMI mode=16 device_number=0 ! xvimagesink sync=false

gst-launch-1.0 decklinksrc connection=Component mode=16 device_number=0 ! xvimagesink sync=false
```

I fail, however, at grabbing in 1080p50 (1080p60 doesn't work either). None of the decklinksrc supported 1080p/1080i modes are working (modes 5-15). The behaviour is as follows:

- Modes 13-15: The pipeline either aborts with an error "gst_decklink_src_start: enable video input failed".
- Modes 5-12: GstSystemClock is initialized, but I'm getting perpetual "gst_decklink_src_start: enable video input failed" debug messages while no video pop up is shown.

Here are the debug results:

```
GST_DEBUG=2,decklink*:6 gst-launch-1.0 decklinksrc connection=HDMI mode=13 device_number=0 ! xvimagesink sync=false

0:00:00.029336645  7092      0x2114780 DEBUG            decklinksrc gstdecklinksrc.cpp:610:gst_decklink_src_audio_src_query:<decklinksrc0:audiosrc> query: caps query: 0x1fadf20, GstQueryCaps, filter=(GstCaps)NULL, caps=(GstCaps)NULL;
0:00:00.029422425  7092      0x2114780 DEBUG            decklinksrc gstdecklinksrc.cpp:610:gst_decklink_src_audio_src_query:<decklinksrc0:audiosrc> query: caps query: 0x1fae000, GstQueryCaps, filter=(GstCaps)NULL, caps=(GstCaps)NULL;
0:00:00.029487787  7092      0x2114780 DEBUG            decklinksrc gstdecklinksrc.cpp:635:gst_decklink_src_video_src_query:<decklinksrc0:videosrc> query: caps query: 0x1fae050, GstQueryCaps, filter=(GstCaps)NULL, caps=(GstCaps)NULL;
0:00:00.029542241  7092      0x2114780 DEBUG            decklinksrc gstdecklinksrc.cpp:635:gst_decklink_src_video_src_query:<decklinksrc0:videosrc> query: caps query: 0x1fae0f0, GstQueryCaps, filter=(GstCaps)NULL, caps=(GstCaps)NULL;
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
0:00:00.031354803  7092      0x2114780 DEBUG            decklinksrc gstdecklinksrc.cpp:419:gst_decklink_src_start:<decklinksrc0> start
0:00:00.539748563  7092      0x2114780 ERROR            decklinksrc gstdecklinksrc.cpp:507:gst_decklink_src_start: enable video input failed
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...


GST_DEBUG=2,decklink*:6 gst-launch-1.0 decklinksrc connection=HDMI mode=9 device_number=0 ! xvimagesink sync=false 

0:00:00.029576730  7158      0x123e780 DEBUG            decklinksrc gstdecklinksrc.cpp:610:gst_decklink_src_audio_src_query:<decklinksrc0:audiosrc> query: caps query: 0x10d7f20, GstQueryCaps, filter=(GstCaps)NULL, caps=(GstCaps)NULL;
0:00:00.029675031  7158      0x123e780 DEBUG            decklinksrc gstdecklinksrc.cpp:610:gst_decklink_src_audio_src_query:<decklinksrc0:audiosrc> query: caps query: 0x10d8000, GstQueryCaps, filter=(GstCaps)NULL, caps=(GstCaps)NULL;
0:00:00.029777155  7158      0x123e780 DEBUG            decklinksrc gstdecklinksrc.cpp:635:gst_decklink_src_video_src_query:<decklinksrc0:videosrc> query: caps query: 0x10d8050, GstQueryCaps, filter=(GstCaps)NULL, caps=(GstCaps)NULL;
0:00:00.029852252  7158      0x123e780 DEBUG            decklinksrc gstdecklinksrc.cpp:635:gst_decklink_src_video_src_query:<decklinksrc0:videosrc> query: caps query: 0x10d80f0, GstQueryCaps, filter=(GstCaps)NULL, caps=(GstCaps)NULL;
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
0:00:00.031620092  7158      0x123e780 DEBUG            decklinksrc gstdecklinksrc.cpp:419:gst_decklink_src_start:<decklinksrc0> start
0:00:00.062865572  7158      0x10d7f20 DEBUG            decklinksrc gstdecklinksrc.cpp:746:gst_decklink_src_task:<decklinksrc0> task
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
0:00:00.385527986  7158      0x125ad90 DEBUG            decklinksrc capture.cpp:99:VideoInputFrameArrived:<decklinksrc0> Frame received - No input signal detected
0:00:00.410565841  7158      0x125ad90 DEBUG            decklinksrc capture.cpp:99:VideoInputFrameArrived:<decklinksrc0> Frame received - No input signal detected
0:00:00.435524012  7158      0x125ad90 DEBUG            decklinksrc capture.cpp:99:VideoInputFrameArrived:<decklinksrc0> Frame received - No input signal detected
0:00:00.485837880  7158      0x125ad90 DEBUG            decklinksrc capture.cpp:99:VideoInputFrameArrived:<decklinksrc0> Frame received - No input signal detected
```

I was able to reproduce the issue on a different machine using another Intensity Pro card. 
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the Intensity Pro card doesn't support 1080p50 or 1080p60 formats. The solution is to either stick to 720p or upgrade to the Intensity Pro 4K model.

For more details, see https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=46452

Comment: [Intensity Pro formats](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/DeckLinkCapabilities/Data/Intensity%20Pro%20%2810.4%29.md#L230): 1080p up to 30, 1080i up to 60, 720p60; [Intensity Pro 4K formats](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/DeckLinkCapabilities/Data/Intensity%20Pro%204K%20%2810.4%29.md#L263).